# ¿Como añadir Leyendas al Mapa en gvNix?

Tags: spring-mvc, gvnix, spring-roo

Me gustaría saber si se podria añadir las leyendas a las capas WMS agregados en gvNix y como se haria.

No sé como podria especificar tanto lo que necesito hacer entonces pongo una imagen como referencia.

Quisiera agregar los legends de cada capa que agrego de esa forma, en la esquina del mapa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste seria mi código en show.jspx del mapa que muestro.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:components="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/geo/components"
xmlns:geo="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/geo"
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:layer="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/geo/layers"
xmlns:layer-toc="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/geo/layers/toc"
xmlns:layer-tool="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/geo/layers/tools"
xmlns:tool="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/geo/tools" version="2.0">

<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<geo:map id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa" projection="EPSG3857"
    z="3aYnlV4HPZq3DrigFvWG8lxF++c=">

    <geo:components id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_components">
        <components:coordinates centerInputCoordinates="true"
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_coordinates" />

        <components:scale id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_scale" />
    </geo:components>

    <geo:toc id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toc"
        z="+MeANZ7lrQ3PHfF88iYJKjjbAyE=">

        <geo:toc-toolbar id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toc_toolbar"
            z="user-managed">
            <tool:opacity id="opacity_slider" z="user-managed" />
        </geo:toc-toolbar>

        <layer:tile allowDisable="false"
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_default_layer"
            url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?bar"
            z="sKKvxQpO3LQFui93VegdYDtJKSE=" />


        <layer:entity filterType="auto" id="l_org_cite_pese_dominio_Estacion"
            path="/estacions" pk="id" selection="true"
            z="fXDq1x3/hgf9UGoxlV2AHiUbFD0=">

            <layer:entity-field field="ubicacion" icon="glyphicon-map-marker"
                iconLibrary="glyphicon"
                id="l_org_cite_pese_dominio_Estacion_ubicacion"
                labelingProperty="codPese" markerColor="darkred" showInfo="true"
                z="0oVQrurrzX/dVZ4cdNJ51XLWsoo=" />
        </layer:entity>

        <layer:wms crs="EPSG4326" format="image/png"
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_limitaciones"
            layers="PesePy:Limites_PY" transparent="true"
            url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PesePy/wms?" version="1.1.1"
            z="k8i1DhIaSY4wyNWXZ8HPQUpMR8E=">

        </layer:wms>

        <layer:wms crs="EPSG4326" format="image/png"
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_Departamentos"
            layers="PesePy:dptos_py" transparent="true"
            url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PesePy/wms?" version="1.1.1"
            z="S9Y1+dZNhp6mNujRQqjTTZMJhFY=" />
    </geo:toc>
    <geo:toolbar id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toolbar"
        z="i1G1w+X/VoTC6Fs5n93xljF7bY8=">
        <tool:print id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_print" />
        <tool:zoom-select-all id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_zoomall" />
    </geo:toolbar>
</geo:map>
```